# Handle dictionary collision in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, hashtable, collision

I currently have the code below working fine:

Can someone help me solve the collision created from having two keys with the same number in the dictionary?

I tried multiple approach (not listed here) to try create an array to handle it but my approaches are still unsuccessful.

I am using #python3.7

```
def find_key(dic1, n):
    '''
    Return the key '3' from the dict
    below.
    '''
    d = {}
    for x, y in dic1.items():
        # swap keys and values
        # and update the result to 'd'
        d[y] = x
    try:
        if n in d:
            return d[y]
    except Exception as e:
        return (e)

dic1 = {'james':2,'david':3}
# Case to test that return ‘collision’
# comment 'dic1' above and replace it by
# dic1 below to create a 'collision'
# dic1 = {'james':2,'david':3, 'sandra':3}
n = 3
print(find_key(dic1,n))
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Two keys with the same data isn't really a collision, per se... it's simply not how dicts work. A collision is when the hash values of two different keys are the same. Linearly looping over the dict doesn't make much sense to me either--can you clarify what you are trying to achieve? Thanks!

Comment: The answer to your question depends on what you want to do when there are collisions. Do you want to get all keys with the specified value?

Comment: That's not a collision, however if you make a reverse lookup dict, it would be a collision. Or, you could have your function return a generator which yields all the keys that have the matching value.

Comment: @KennyOstrom yes, or a list comprehension. And note they produce a collision because they do create a reverse dict...

Comment: What is `find_key(dic1,n)` *supposed* to return? `'david'`, `'sandra'`, either one, or both? Note, creating a reverse dictionary inside your function to get a single key is sort of pointless to begin with.

Comment: I understand better....What I want to achieve is because we have two keys which data are 3 from the new dictionary `d` created, i want the function to return those two values. In this case I want the dictionary `d` to show anything identical or similar to {2:`James`, 3: [`David `,`sandra`]} @ggorlen @jirassimok  @juanpa.arrivillaga @SpghttCd

Comment: So you want a dict with list values for each key? That's pretty straightforward. Use a `d = collections.defaultdict(list)` and `d[key].append(val)`. Then `d[key]` gives you back the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know there should be multiple returns, so plan for that in advance.

```
def find_keys_for_value(d, value):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if v == value:
            yield k

data = {'james': 2, 'david': 3, 'sandra':3}
for result in find_keys_for_value(data, 3):
    print (result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def find_key(dct, n):
    dd = defaultdict(list)
    for x, y in dct.items():
        dd[y].append(x)
    return dd[n]

dic1 = {'james':2, 'david':3, 'sandra':3}
print(find_key(dic1, 3))
print(find_key(dic1, 2))
print(find_key(dic1, 1))
```

Output:

```
['david', 'sandra']
['james']
[]
```

Building a defaultdict from all keys and values is only justified if you will repeatedly search for keys of the same dict given different values, though. Otherwise, the approach of Kenny Ostrom is preferrable. In any case, the above makes little sense if left as it stands.

If you are not at ease with generators and `yield`, here is the approach of Kenny Ostrom translated to lists (less efficient than generators, better than the above for one-shot searches):

```
def find_key(dct, n):
    return [x for x, y in dct.items() if y == n]
```

The output is the same as above.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for. thank you @waltertross

Comment: If the data doesn't change, and you need to do many lookups and reverse lookups, then you should build this reverse lookup dict once, and keep it around. O(1) lookup, O(1) reverse lookup, added code and time complexity for changes, but that doesn't matter if your data doesn't change often.